# PHP sets header by itself

Tags: php, header

I have a script on php, that has some output and I set headers there:

```
header("Content-Length: 20".$eol);
header("MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol);
header("Connection: Keep-Alive".$eol);
header("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate".$eol);
header("Host: host".$eol.$eol);
header("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=boundary_.oOo._MzA3NjM=NTczNw==NDM1Ng==".$eol);
echo $res;
```

I set content-length, but when I check my script the page sets content length as strlen of `$res`. What's the problem?

**EDIT** So as I understand code is correct. Problem can be in Webserver. (I'm using Apache)
**EDIT** $eol="\r\n".
**EDIT**

```
$res="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
$res .= "Content-Type: application/json".$eol;
$res .= "Content-Length: ".strlen("JSON").$eol.$eol;
$res .= "JSON";
$res.=$eol.$eol;
$res.="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
$res.="Content-Type: image/jpeg".$eol;
$res.="Content-Length: ".strlen("Image").$eol;
$res.=$eol;
$res.="Image";
$res.=$eol.$eol;
$res.="--".$BOUNDARY.$eol;
$res .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".$eol;
$res .= "Content-Length: ".strlen("Vector").$eol;
$res.=$eol;
$res.="Vector";
$res .= $eol.$eol;
$res .= "--".$BOUNDARY."--".$eol;
```

Body of response should use MIME. Java coder that checks it asked me to set content-length that is sum of content-length of each entity.

Comment: Probably your script are treating the content based in your ECHO (displaying).

Comment: Are you sure that it's PHP and not the Web Server or something else further up the chain that's changing it to the correct value?

Comment: From a quick look at the PHP source code I can't find any place that would do this ....

Comment: You do not need to add an EOL to your headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTTP protocol follows the robustness principle as described in [RFC1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122), which states "Be liberal in what you accept, and conservative in what you send". As a result of this principle, **HTTP clients will compensate for and recover from incorrect or misconfigured responses**, or responses that are uncacheable.

<sup>[Source](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/compliance.html)</sup>

Because you've sent an incorrect `Content-Length` value, Apache has corrected it for you.

Comment: So, there is no way to disable it?

Comment: Why would you want to send an incorrect `Content-length` header?

Comment: Watch, do you know something about it?

Comment: It seems like you're outputting multiple types of text with different headers - each time you set `Content-Length` header, it overwrites the previous `Content-Length` header - is this your actual code, or just snippets put in the same code block?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to show a bigger chunk of your code.  What does $eol contain and is the first portion a part of an echo ?  If the html is badly formatted, things appear to get juggled around.  I think this is your problem.  Try an html tester site or addon on your browser.